# TensorFlow: Input for a session to compute a variable? FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value weight_2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to run a TensorFlow session to find out the value of a variable W. Below is my code:

```
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

print(W.dtype)
print(W.initial_value)
print(W.value)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(W)
```

Then I got the following outputs & errors:

```
<dtype: 'float32_ref'>
Tensor("weight_2/initial_value:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
<bound method Variable.value of <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7f031f36a470>>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
    971     try:
--> 972       return fn(*args)
    973     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
    953                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
--> 954                                  status, run_metadata)
    955 

/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    462           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 463           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    464   finally:

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value weight_2
     [[Node: _send_weight_2_0 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=true, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=-1169476299400319384, tensor_name="weight_2:0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](weight_2)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-892407d423e3> in <module>()
      7 
      8 sess = tf.Session()
----> 9 sess.run(W)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    715     try:
    716       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 717                          run_metadata_ptr)
    718       if run_metadata:
    719         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    913     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    914       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 915                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    916     else:
    917       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    963     if handle is None:
    964       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
--> 965                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
    966     else:
    967       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
    983         except KeyError:
    984           pass
--> 985       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
    986 
    987   def _extend_graph(self):

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value weight_2
     [[Node: _send_weight_2_0 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=true, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=-1169476299400319384, tensor_name="weight_2:0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](weight_2)]]
```

I am guessing I need a formula of W (or something like that) for the session to run, but not sure exactly what is needed ... What exactly needs to be provided so a session can compute the value of a variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function name `initialize_all_variables` is a bit misleading (and has been changed in 0.12). It returns an op you need to run. `W` won't be initialized until you call `sess.run(init)`.

`W.initial_value` shows the value that *it will be initialized with*, from what I read in the docs (emphasis mine):

> `tf.Variable.initial_value`
>
> Returns the Tensor used as the initial value for the variable.
>
> Note that this is different from `initialized_value()` which runs the op
>   that initializes the variable before returning its value. **This method
>   returns the tensor that is used by the op that initializes the
>   variable.**

Comment: Thanks. But why W.initial_value still print : Tensor("weight_2/initial_value:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)  even though I don't call initialize_all_variables ? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer to explain what `initial_value` is.